# if-else statement strlen not working php

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, strlen

I am trying to create a working registration validation however I have a problem. The validations work but there is an error, even if the user enters the correct information the INSERT statement is not executed. However, when the "elseif" statement is removed then the error is echoed on the interface but the data is still INSERTED even if there is an error in the user form; such as the password only having letters. I Would be grateful if anyone could fix this error. The complete validation is below.
Thanks
Wasim

```
<?php include "connection2.php" ?>
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($errors)) { 
    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 

        $firstname=$_POST['Firstname'];
        $lastname=$_POST['Lastname'];
        $username=$_POST['Username'];
        $password= $_POST['Password'];
        $email=$_POST['Email'];


        if ($username&&$password&&$email) {

            if (strlen($username)>10) {
                echo "Username is too long (Max 10 Characters)";
            }
            else {           

                //check password length
                if (strlen($password)>15||strlen($password)<5) {
                    echo "Password must be 5 to 15 characters<br>";
                }
                if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password)) {
                    echo "Password must include at least one number!<br>";
                }
                if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $password)) {
                    echo "Password must include at least one letter!<br>";
                }

                elseif ((!strlen($username) >10) and

                        (!strlen($password)>15||!strlen($password)<5) and     
                        (preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password)) and 
                        (preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $password))) {


                    $sql = mysql_query
                        ("INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname,username, password, email)         

            VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$username',  

            '$password','$email')");

                    md5($password);
                    //register the user!

                    echo "Your Are Now a Member";




                }

            }
        }

        mysql_close(); 
    }}
else { ?>
    <?php }
?>
```

Comment: First thing you need to do is standardize your indenting to make this easier to read.

Comment: Also stop using mysql_*. use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: try if this username is valid: '); DROP TABLE users;--

Comment: Can you mention the input string which you are testing and while testing what out it is giving

Comment: @Wasim Patel  please mark answer which give you the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your `elseif` is only attached to the last `if`. And I'm not sure if you got all the inverted logic correct in it. But a simpler solution is to just set a variable that indicates whether any of the validation checks failed, and test this.

```
if ($username && $password && $email) {

    if (strlen($username)>10) {
        echo "Username is too long (Max 10 Characters)";
    }
    else {           
        $error = false;
        //check password length
        if (strlen($password)>15||strlen($password)<5) {
            echo "Password must be 5 to 15 characters<br>";
            $error = true;
        }
        if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password)) {
            echo "Password must include at least one number!<br>";
            $error = true;
        }
        if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $password)) {
            echo "Password must include at least one letter!<br>";
            $error = true;
        }

        if (!$error) {
            // insert new users
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP the elseif and 'else if' constructs may need more braces, see the note on http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Additionaly check operator precedence.  Using the keywords 'and' and 'or' to have have the same weight as using '||' or '&&'.  I would recommend adding additional braces and parenthesis to make the conditionals even more clear.

Comment: Thankyou @anant kumar singh. All the validations are fully working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think your structure is wrong a little.

```
<?php include "connection2.php" ?>
 <?php
 session_start();
    if (empty($errors)) { 
     if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 


    $firstname=$_POST['Firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['Lastname'];
    $username=$_POST['Username'];
    $password= $_POST['Password'];
    $email=$_POST['Email'];


     if ($username&&$password&&$email)
           {

          if (strlen($username)>10)
          {
             echo "Username is too long (Max 10 Characters)";
          }
          elseif(strlen($password)>15||strlen($password)<5)
          {           
             echo "Password must be 5 to 15 characters<br>";
          }
       elseif (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password)) {
          echo "Password must include at least one number!<br>";
        }
        elseif (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $password)) {
          echo "Password must include at least one letter!<br>";
       }

          else ((!strlen($username) >10) and

            (!strlen($password)>15||!strlen($password)<5) and     
            (preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password)) and 
           (preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $password)))
              {


      $sql = mysql_query
       ("INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname,username, password, email)         

        VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$username',  

        '$password','$email')");

           md5($password);
           //register the user!

               echo "Your Are Now a Member";




      }

        }
      }




      mysql_close(); 
           }}
            else { ?>
             <?php }
                ?>
```

Hope that helps. but I would also save each error in array and display in the end.